# Maintenance mode using S3 + CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm serving a single page app that is hosted on S3 and exposed to the web via CloudFront. When I'm performing maintenance on my API, I'd like to have a manual switch that causes the request to my app to render a maintenance page.

I can put the maintenance HTML (or json) to the S3. How to configure CloudFront to return the maintenance site when I switch the maintenance mode on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a Lambda@Edge function to generate your static "maintenance" response: 
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-static-web-server

When you want to activate it, select **Viewer Request** trigger and use the Lambda function's ARN on the settings page for the Cache Behavior(s) that you want to return the maintenance message, and save changes.  To deactivate it, remove it.  The change is usually processed within a very short period of time.

This will accomplish your purpose because a Viewer Request trigger fires *before* the CloudFront cache is checked, and if it generates a response, the response is returned without checking the cache and the generated response is not stored in the CloudFront cache -- so any cached content will still be there after you remove the trigger.

Note that the first time you actually associate a function like this with a CloudFront distribution, I *believe* that you need to "enable trigger and replicate" in the Lambda console so that the Lambda function is globally accessible when CloudFront needs it.  You don't have to associate it with the "real" CloudFront distribution when testing this -- you can create a second one for testing -- but a function version needs to go through this replication cycle before it can be used in the CloudFront console.  Functions for use with Lambda@Edge must be created in the us-east-1 region, and are then replicated to all regions so that a CloudFront edge can invoke it via its nearest region.  Lambda@Edge functions are always referenced by their numeric version id.  Function aliases, including the magic string `$LATEST` are not used by Lambda@Edge.

Comment: Nice! This is what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @MaticJurglič great.  I added another note to the end to potentially save you some troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an [invalidation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) of specific files on CloudFront, but that means that you'll have to overwrite the current web app during maintenance and then restore it (and invalidate again) once you're back up.

I think the best solution is to add support for maintenance mode in your app and periodically (and on service not available errors) check for a flag somewhere (typically a static file served over CloudFront with a short max age) and if it says you're in maintenance mode freeze the app and display a dialog telling the user that the API is under maintenance - or just lock functionality that requires API access and let the user continue using read-only access with cached data if that's possible.

With the latter solution you only need to upload a file to S3 and remember to remove/replace it again once you're finished - you can even include a message (a changelog perhaps?) that the app displays to your users.