# AWS cloudFront maintenance page

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gitlab, amazon-cloudfront

I have a web site deployed from an s3.and there is also a page maintenance.html in an other S3 bucket. I want to automate the appearance of the maintenance page during the maintenance period. I can do it manually, but I want to write a script, a lambda function, GitLab pipeline or GitLabCI which changes the behavior origin automatically. Like this the web developers can put the maintenance page without need to call the prod team to do it.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maintenance mode using S3 + CloudFront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904990/maintenance-mode-using-s3-cloudfront)

Comment: I'd like to have an automated switch that causes the request to my app to render a maintenance page. can you help me please!